# Mordell equation with prime-squared constant

Tags: number-theory, divisibility, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves, mordell-curves

I'm interested in a specific case of the Mordell equation:
$$E: y^2=x^3+k$$
where $k=p^2$ for some prime $p$.

Most of the literature I've been able to find regarding the Mordell equation either explicitly assumes $k$ to be square-free or avoids the case altogether.

I want to show that the torsion subgroup of $E(\mathbb{Q})$ is (isomorphic to) $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$.

By the Nagell-Lutz theorem, we can narrow down the possibilities to
$$y \in \{\pm{1},\pm{3},\pm{p},\pm{3p},\pm{p^2},\pm{3p^2}\}$$

By a factoring argument, I can prove that the $y=\pm{1}$ case yields no solutions (except a specific side-case for $p=3$ that yields a non-torsion point).

I can't seem to uncover an analogous argument, or really any argument,  for the $y=\pm{3}$ case, which boils down to solving
$$x^3=9-p^2=(3-p)(3+p)$$

Here's what I know:

1. $x$ must be an integer if it is a rational solution;
2. $9-x^3$ doesn't factor over $\mathbb{Z}$ so we can't use the same argument as in the $p=\pm{1}$ case;
3. $p=2$ yields no solutions, so we can assume that $p$ is odd, which leads to $x$ being even, which in turn shows that $8\vert(3-p)(3+p)$.

I've tried to extend out point #3 above but keep on running into dead ends. Are there other techniques that I'm missing here? Any pointers would be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: $\gcd(3-p,3+p)$ divides $(3+p)-(3-p)=2p$ and also $(3+p)+(3-p)=6$, so (ignoring the case $p=3$) it must be $1$ or $2$. So either $3-p$ and $3+p$ are both cubes, or one is twice a  cube and the other is four times a cube. That should be a help.

Comment: Thanks Gerry. When $\gcd(3-p,3+p)=1$ and both terms are cubes, then their sum is 6, which we can directly confirm isn't possible. When one is twice a cube and the other four times a cube it's still less clear to me. I tried to "fill out" the twos (by multiplying by four and two respectively) and adding, then factoring the result as the sum of two cubes. I end up with $9-p=4(r+s)(r^2-rs+s^2)$, which doesn't seem to lead anywhere.

Comment: From $3-p=2r^3$, $3+p=4s^3$ you immediately get $p=4s^3-3$, and it's clear that most primes can't be written that way.

Comment: I'm able to find 6 distinct primes less than 100,000 that can be written this way, and it's unclear to me why there wouldn't be (even infinitely many) more. The workings of this particular strand of Diophantine analysis, while obvious to the initiated, is pretty inscrutable to me. I'm able to understand Dan's analysis below, but I'm also curious about this approach; are there any books or other resources you might recommend to get more comfortable with claims like the one you left me with? Thanks!

Comment: That most primes can't be written as $4s^3-3$ has nothing to do with Diophantine analysis. Consider that the number of primes up to $n$ is roughly $n/\log n$ (the Prime Number Theorem), while the number of numbers up to $n$ of the form $4s^3-3$ is roughly $\root3\of{n/4}$, which is much, much smaller (try calculating both for, say, $n=10^9$). So, most primes can't be written that way. Then impose the other condition, $p=3-2r^3$, an expression which similarly excludes most primes, and imagine how dificult it would be to find a prime that can be expressed in both forms. But (continued)

Comment: (continued) while this gives a strong heuristic, an actual proof like Dan's beats it any day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative view.
Let $T(x,y)$ be a torsion point on the given curve $E$ over $\Bbb Q$ with (affine) equation
$$ E\ :\qquad Y^2 = X^3 + k\ ,\ k=p^2\ ,\ p>3\text{ prime .}$$

From the OP, we already know that only points $(x,y)$ with $y$ among one of the $12$ divisors in $\Bbb Z$ of $3p^2$ are possible. (Since $y^2$ divides the discriminant $-27k^2=-27p^4$.)
And $y$ determines the value of $x$, since $x\to x^3$ is injective on $\Bbb Z$. The values $\pm p$ and $\pm p^2$ are excluded. So there remain only $8$ possibilities.

---

The $3$-torsion points are simple $(0,\pm p)$. (Easy computations inserted for the convenience of a community reader only at the end.)
So the torsion order is either $3$ or $6$. In case of a $6$-torsion, we would have a point of $2$-torsion. This is easily excluded, since the polynomial $X^3-p^2$ has no rational roots. So the torsion order is $3$.

$\square$

---

Addendum: Computation of the $3$-torsion points.

We compute both sides of the equality $T= -2T$.
The point $T$ is $(x,y)$. Let us compute $-2T=(x',y')$.
The slope $m$ in $(x,y)$ comes from the formal differential $2Y\; dY=3X^3\; dX$, it is
$$m=\frac{3x^2}{2y}\ .$$
The components of $-2T$ are thus given by the intersection of the line $(Y-y)=m(X-x)$ with $E$. plugging in $Y = m(X-x)+y$ into the equation of $E$ we have $(m(X-x)+y)^2=X^3+k$, and the three solutions are $x,x,x'$. Vieta for the coefficient in $X^2$ gives $x'$, so
$$
\begin{aligned}
x' &= m^2-x-x=\frac{9x^4}{4y^2}-2x\ ,\\
y' &= y + m(x'-x)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
From $y'=y$ we get either $x'=x$, so $T=O$, or else $m=0$, so $x=0$. The corresponding points are $T_\pm =(0,\pm A)$, both torsion points. (Opposite to each other.)

---

Addendum:
An other possibility to eliminate a torsion point of the shape $(x,\pm3)=\pm(x,3)$ is as follows. It is enough to consider only the plus sign, we start with $y=3$, and $P(x,3)$ torsion, and compute $2P=(x',y')$, which is also torsion. We expect an "ugly" expression, but $y'$ is also constrained to be one of the divisors of $3p^2$. With the above notations...
$$
\begin{aligned} 
m &=\frac{3x^2}{2y}=\frac{x^2}2\ ,\\
x' &= m^2-2x=\frac {x^4}4-2x\ ,\\
y' &= y+m(x'-x)=3+\frac {x^2}2\left(\frac{x^4}4-3x\right)\\
&=3+\frac{(9-p^2)}2\cdot\frac{(9-p^2)-12}4
=\frac 18(p^4-6p^2-3)
\end{aligned} 
$$
The last number is integer and a divisor of $3p^2$. It is $-3/8\ne 0$ in the field $\Bbb F_p$. So it is relatively prime to $p$, thus a divisor of $3$, and there are four cases ($\pm 1$, $\pm 3$) to be checked.

Comment: Thank you Dan! I wouldn't have thought to approach the problem like this, and I'm thankful for the reframing! Particularly the second addendum, which directly addresses my question; I hadn't thought to restrict 2P with the same y-values under the assumption that P is a torsion point, and this makes the problem quite tractable. Cheers!

Comment: Would you mind taking a look at this other [closely related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3771975) of mine, @dan_fulea?  Thank you!  =)